# Solving numerically a non-linear equation.

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

How is the more appropriate numerical method to solve the equation

$$\cos(2\pi x)+\cos \left(\frac{2\pi N}{x}\right)=2,$$ for a given $N$?

Notice that if $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x\mid N$.

Comment: do you have a numerical value for $N$?

Comment: No. It is for $x$. I see now that each term must be $1$. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you need numerical method.

As for real $A,\cos A\le1$

So, we need $\cos(2\pi x)=\cos\dfrac{2\pi N}x=1$

Also, $\cos B=1\implies B=2m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer.